# Socket.io listen methods don't listen after sometime or when Internet connection is lost

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm working in a chat feature of an app, so I'm using [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) with node and swift for the client-side in the iOS app.

I have a class like this in some parte of the app:

```
   class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
       // Socket manager instantiation
    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
    static let urls = EndpointsURLs()
    var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: urls.urlSocket)!, config: [.log(false), .forcePolling(true), .doubleEncodeUTF8(true)])

    override init() {
        super.init()  
    }

    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()  
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    } 

   // Emit events:
   func emitExample(argument: String){
        // Custom emit event
        let data: NSDictionary = ["argument": argument]
        socket.emit("local join", data)
   }

   ...

   }
```

I use the method **establishConnection()** in the AppDelegate.swift.

In the viewController I have a method similar to this one:

```
func listenEvents(){
     SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.off("message")
     SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("message") { (data, ack) in
         // Do some actions

     }

     ....

     SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.off("otherEvent")
     SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.on("otherEvent") { (data, ack) in
         // Do some actions

     }}
```

This code works good but only for some minutes. Then, one or both participants in conversation don't receive any new message. In other words, the socket-client code in swift doesn't listen anymore after a certain time. 
I have noticed that this error happens always when I disconnect from internet and reconnect it.

I have tried reconnecting socket, running the "on methods" each some time or with events (such as internet connection lost) during chat, but with no results.

Why socket stop listen events after some messages?

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample to handle connection lost of a socket it works fine with me
maybe this could help

```
func getChatMessage(_ UserLoginDetails: [AnyHashable : Any]?, withCompletion completionHandler: @escaping (_ Server_Response: [AnyHashable]?) -> Void) {
var UserLoginDetails = UserLoginDetails
if let UserLoginDetails = UserLoginDetails {
    print("\(UserLoginDetails)")
}

var userdata = UserLoginDetails
let roomid = userdata?["roomId"] as? String
UserLoginDetails = nil

if socket.status() != SocketIOStatusConnected {
    socket.on("connect", callback: { data, ack in
        if userdata != nil {
            self.socket.emit("getMessages", with: [userdata])
            self.socket.off(roomid)
            self.socket.on(roomid, callback: { data, ack in

                completionHandler(data)
            })
            userdata = nil
        }
    })
} else {
if userdata != nil {
    socket.emit("getMessages", with: [userdata])
    socket.off(roomid)
    socket.on(roomid, callback: { data, ack in
        completionHandler(data)
    })
    userdata = nil
}}socket.connect()
```